# Write on PTM Master Pseudoterminal

Tags: tty, pseudoterminal

When we use the `write()` system call function to write on a ptm master, the `pty_write()` function will be triggered of because `/dev/ptmx` is a device file.
The `write()` prototype is :

```c
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

where `fd` is the file descriptor which has been obtained from the call to open `/dev/ptmx`.

The `pty_write()` prototype is :

```c
int pty_write(struct tty_struct *tty, const unsigned char *buf, int c);
```

where `tty` is the ptm.

As you can see, both functions have a buffer and a number of bytes to write as parameters. but the third parameter is different. The `write()` function has a file descriptor and `pty_write()` function has tty structure.

How does the kernel link a file descriptor of `write()` function to the right tty (ptm) of `pty_write()` function?